# How does Contract.Exists add value?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am just starting to learn about the code contracts library that comes standard with VS2010. One thing I am running into right away is what some of the contract clauses really mean.

For example, how are these two statements different?

```
Contract.Requires(!mycollection.Any(a => a.ID == newID));
Contract.Requires(!Contract.Exists(mycollection, a => a.ID == newID));
```

In other words, what does Contract.Exists do in practical purposes, either for a developer using my function, or for the static code analysis system?

Comment: @Chris Pebble, the possible duplicate talks about the difference between List.Exists to IEnumerable.Any. This one is related to Contract.Exists - it's a different context.

Comment: Good point. Pardon the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. According to the Code Contracts User Manual, section 2.7.2:

"It is also possible to use the extension method System.Linq.Enumerable.Any instead of Contract.Exists ."

So they are equivalent. I will use Any instead of Exists, so it is consistent with the rest of our code.

Answer (score 4):

The version that uses `Contract.Exists` is preferred due to its declarative nature. Another advantage is that the framework knows this contract and it has better chance of being "caught" in static analysis.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "preferred due to its declarative nature"?

Also, does static analysis actually work with delegates? I would expect that the fact you can put arbitrary code into that lambda would nullify any possible static analysis.